# fetching an Object from Action Item and displaying on View without Page refresh Using Ajax and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

```
 public class vendorData
        {
        public int VCode { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult OnGetVendorCode(string VendorName)
        {
            var VendorMaster = _context.VendorMaster.ToList();
            var VendorCodes = from O in VendorMaster where O.CompanyID == Company && O.VendorName == VendorName select O.VendorCode;
            var currency= from O in VendorMaster where O.CompanyID == Company && O.VendorName == VendorName select O.Currency;
            vendorData vendorData = new vendorData();
            vendorData.VCode = VendorCodes.FirstOrDefault();
            vendorData.currency = currency.FirstOrDefault();

            return new JsonResult(vendorData);
        }

function GetPOVendorCode(ID) {
    $.ajax(
        {
            data: { VendorName: ID },
            url: '/Purchase/POGenerals/Create/?handler=VendorCode',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                const myJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
                alert(myJSON.VCode);
                
            }
        });
}
```

How can I access each object item through my Ajax call? and save it in a variable so that I could use that on my page? Is there any other better way? I am using ASP razor pages and trying to update other text boxes of the purchase order when I select the vendor name

Comment: Hi @Adnan UI Haq, any update ?

Answer (score 0):

The response `data` is the correct object so that no need use `JSON.stringify(data);`.
Also the response `data` is `camel` case format.

In summary, just use `data.vCode` to get the value.

[image]